# How to get all Amazon MWS flatfiles from API or any other method

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-mws

I am trying to get all flatfiles from amazon MWS, But there is no way to get all these flatfiles from API. We use this flatfiles to make field required in our software

Is there any way to get this Flatfiles? If we download these flatfiles manually it will consume more time

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a similar thing in node.js using amazon-mws wrapper.

There are many flat files, one of them is *GET_FLAT_FILE_ORDERS_DATA*, each one of them associated with some API operation. [Refer to this for more in-depth knowledge](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_ReportType.html#ReportTypeCategories__OrderReports).

*GET_FLAT_FILE_ORDERS_DATA* is associated with Request report operation.

Step1: request report

```
const MwsApi = require('amazon-mws')
const amazonMws = new MwsApi();
const requestReport = async (accessKey, accessSecret, version, 
reportType, sellerId, mwsAuthToken, startDate, endDate) => {
amazonMws.setApiKey(accessKey, accessSecret);
amazonMws.setHost('mws.amazonservices.in');

try {
    const response = await amazonMws.reports.submit({
        'Version': version,
        'Action': 'RequestReport',
        'SellerId': sellerId,
        'MWSAuthToken': mwsAuthToken,
        'ReportType': reportType,
        'StartDate': startDate,
        'EndDate': endDate

    });
    // console.log(response);
    return response;

} catch (error) {
    log.info("ERROR!!" + error)
    return error;
}
```

};

This will return a reportRequestId which will be used in the next step

Step 2: Get Report

```
const getReport = async (accessKey, accessSecret, version, sellerId, mwsAuthToken, reportRequestId) => {
amazonMws.setApiKey(accessKey, accessSecret);
amazonMws.setHost('mws.amazonservices.in');

try {
    const response = await amazonMws.reports.search({
        'Version': '2009-01-01',
        'Action': 'GetReport',
        'SellerId': sellerId,
        'MWSAuthToken': mwsAuthToken,
        'ReportId': reportRequestId,
    });
    return response;

} catch (error) {
    log.info("ERROR!!" + error)
    return error;
}
```

};

Visit this https://blog.learningdollars.com/2020/05/15/how-to-implement-amazons-mws-api-in-node-js-and-javascript-to-generate-frontend-reports/ for detailed understanding

Here is my profile: https://blog.learningdollars.com/author/lakshaygupta21/

Comment: You don't need to add a new answer, editing the deleted answer is sufficient. Also, can you be more explicit about the fact that you're the author of the blog you've linked to?

Comment: I edited the deleted answer but it's not getting displayed publically so I added a new one.  Also related to the authorship of the blog, here is my profile https://blog.learningdollars.com/author/lakshaygupta21/

Comment: Thanks, but that disclosure needs to be in the answer itself, not in a comment.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was unclear. Please add the disclosure that you mentioned in the comment. If you don't add that to the answer, this will be considered spam.